# Angular - template checkboxes in ngFor are linked

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-ngmodel, ng-template

For a role assignment website, it is possible to assign a role to a user for a specific application. These roles can have some linked "entities", such as Brands. The content of such entities can be repeated for multiple roles, so I placed it in a ng-template. Based on the linked property, the template is setup. At the same time, there can multiple *Brands* templates for multiple roles.

In the template, there are checkboxes which are bound to brand countries. When I check a brand country, the same brand country of another role.

Currently, I have no idea how these are bound to each other.

E.g. I've two roles AssignmentAdmin and UserAdmin. Both roles are linked to Brands. When I check Belgium in the TestMichael brand, the same country/brand is checked for UserAdmin.

[image]

roles JSON, this body is complemented with other Brands data, but this is the basic structure of **assigned** countries.

```
"applications": [
    {
        "id": "173043ae-00f4-49d5-ba15-41488fc09ef4",
        "name": "MyAccount",
        "roles": [
            {
                "id": "e187b0d2-4b3d-60a3-9d14-1a6f48b465b8",
                "name": "UserAdmin",
                "brands": [
                    {
                        "id": "b2f3815c-1501-13b1-9d14-e03e18b0aa67",
                        "name": "Reynaers",
                        "countries": [
                            {
                                "id": "b2f3815c-1501-13b1-9d14-e03e2825e967",
                                "country": "BE",
                                "companyTypes": null
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "b2f3815c-1501-13b1-9d14-e03e406ff567",
                                "country": "DZ",
                                "companyTypes": null
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "b2f3815c-1501-13b1-9d14-e03e90860168",
                                "country": "AT",
                                "companyTypes": null
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "b2f3815c-1501-13b1-9d14-e03e7846d267",
                                "country": "AU",
                                "companyTypes": null
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "applications": null,
                "companyTypes": null,
                "linked": "Brands"
            },
            {
                "id": "e187b0d2-4b3d-60a3-9d14-646fb0402ecf",
                "name": "AssignmentAdmin",
                "brands": [
                    {
                        "id": "b2f3815c-1501-13b1-9d14-e03e18b0aa67",
                        "name": "Reynaers",
                        "countries": [
                            {
                                "id": "b2f3815c-1501-13b1-9d14-e03e406ff567",
                                "country": "DZ",
                                "companyTypes": null
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "b2f3815c-1501-13b1-9d14-e03e90860168",
                                "country": "AT",
                                "companyTypes": null
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "b2f3815c-1501-13b1-9d14-e03e2825e967",
                                "country": "BE",
                                "companyTypes": null
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "applications": [
                    {
                        "id": "a6656547-2d5b-44f6-8d51-30dd737c1759",
                        "name": "Article",
                        "companyTypes": null
                    }
                ],
                "companyTypes": null,
                "linked": "Brands,Applications"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Create templates

```
<h5 *ngIf="bSelectRoleEntities && role.linked != 'None'">Linked entities of {{role.name}}</h5>
<mat-tab-group *ngIf="bSelectRoleEntities && role.linked != 'None'" animationDuration="0ms" dynamicHeight>
    <mat-tab *ngFor="let linked of role.linked" label="{{linked}}">
        <ng-container #entity [ngTemplateOutlet]="linked == 'Brands' ? Brands : Applications" 
            [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{role: role}" ></ng-container>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Brands template

```
<ng-template #Brands let-role="role">
    <div class="ds-card ds-card--primary">
        <div class="ds-card__body ds-card__body--lg">
        <div>{{role.id}} - {{role.name}}</div>
          <div *ngFor="let brand of role.brands">
            <div class="ds-grid-auto-xl ds-grid-auto-gap-lg" >
              <div class="ds-card ds-card--tertiary ds-card--success">
                <div class="ds-card__body">
                  <details class="ds-details">
                    <summary class="ds-details__summary ds-details__summary--block">
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-2"><h4><span [matBadgeHidden]="brand.assignedCountries === 0"  matBadge="{{brand.assignedCountries}}" matBadgeOverlap="false">{{brand.name}}</span></h4></div>
                          <div class="col-md-3 ds-input-check ds-input-check--inline">
                            <input id="check-{{brand.name}}" type="checkbox" class="ds-input-check__input">
                            <label for="check-{{brand.name}}" class="ds-input-check__label">Assign to all countries</label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input class="form-control inputField" type="text" placeholder="Filter countries" [(ngModel)]="brand.countryFilter" />
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </summary>
                    <div class="col-md-3 box-border" *ngFor="let country of brand.countries">
                      <div class="ds-input-check ds-input-check--inline">
                        <input id="check-{{role.id}}-{{brand.name}}-{{country.country}}" type="checkbox" class="ds-input-check__input" [name]="role.id + brand.name" [(ngModel)]="country.isAssigned" (change)="assignRoleBrands($event,role.id,brand.id,country.id)" >
                        <label for="check-{{role.id}}-{{brand.name}}-{{country.country}}" class="ds-input-check__label"><span><img class="ds-button__icon--left" src="https://flagcdn.com/w20/{{country.country.toLowerCase()}}.png" width="20"/>{{ country.country | translate }}</span></label>
                      </div>
                      <!-- <mat-chip-list selectable multiple>
                        <mat-chip *ngFor="let companyType of country.companyTypes" #c="matChip" (click)="setCountryCompanyType(c, brand.id, country.id, companyType.id)" selected="{{companyType.isAssigned}}">
                          {{companyType.name}}
                        </mat-chip>
                      </mat-chip-list> -->
                    </div>
                  </details>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <br />
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

**EDIT**

The checkbox in the template has a binding method linked to it. This is the code.

```
 assignRoleBrands(e: any, roleId: string, brandId: string, countryId: string) {
      var brand = this.applicationRoleDetail.roles.find(r => r.id == roleId).brands.find(b => b.id == brandId);
      //var brand = this.selectedRole.brands.find(b => b.id == brandId);
      brand.countries.find(c => c.id == countryId).isAssigned = e.currentTarget.checked;
      brand.assignedCountries = brand.countries.filter(c => c.isAssigned).length;

      this.selectedRole.entitiesSet = this.determineEntitiesSet(this.applicationRoleDetail.roles.find(r => r.id == roleId)); //this.selectedRole.brands?.some(b => b.assignedCountries > 0) && this.selectedRole.applications?.some(a => a.assignedApplications > 0);

      console.log(this.applicationRoleDetail);

      this.checkForApplicationChanges();
    }
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: I see you have 2 way binding on the checkbox and a change event, can you show us the change event, just in case that some how generates you issue.

Comment: @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen I've added the binding event.